# Possibly Undefined Array References in Typescript Strict Mode

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, undefined

At work we use Typescript with strict null checking help to catch exceptions caused by null/undefined variables. However we recently came across a bug that Typescript seems to miss. The code below demonstrates it:

```js
interface IMyObj {
    foo: string;
}
const myArr: IMyObj[] = [];
const myObjProp = myArr[0].foo;
console.log(myObjProp);
```

Typescript will compile this without complaint, but when run it will obviously throw a type error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
```

We could of course define all array types in the codebase as `(IMyObj | undefined)[]` instead of `IMyObj[]`, but that seems error prone as well since it'd be easy to miss one.

Is there any way to get Typescript to detect a possibly undefined reference like `myArr[0]`?

Answer (score 3):

You can add this option

```
"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,  /* Include 'undefined' in index signature results */
```

into `"compilerOptions"` object of **tsconfigfile.json** to catch errors depends on undefined array items.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to get Typescript to detect a possibly undefined reference like myArr[0]?

No, and it's very unlikely it will ever be implemented in TypeScript, see the discussion of [this proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778). See also [these](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11122) [issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9235).